# How to select a range of numbers to multiply an hourly wage by

Tags: python

Im reading in a file with employee information on it. First name, last name, hours worked, hourly wage. I need to calculate regular pay, so hourly wage * hours between and including 0 and 40. Also, time and a half which is between 41 and 45, inclusive. My question is how do I only use the hours between 0 and 40 to get the regular pay? This is my current code:

```
def main():
print()
print("This program will compute payroll.")
print("Written by Josh Sollenberger.")
print()

filename = input("Please enter the emplyee file name: ")
infile = open(filename, 'r')
print()
for line in infile:
    first,last,hours,wage = line.split(',')
    while int(hours) >= 0 and int(hours) <= 40:
        regPay = float(wage)*hours
    print(first,last,hours,wage,regPay)
```

main()

This is telling me i'm referencing regPay before assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before, using `min` and `max`

```
regPay = float(wage) * min(int(hours),40)
# min(hours,40) will return hours, unless hours > 40 then it will return 40
OTpay = float(wage) * OVERTIMERATE * max(int(hours)-40,0)
# max(hours-40,0) will return hours-40, unless hours <= 40 then it will return 0
```

The reason it's telling you that you're referencing `regPay` before assignment is because you're ONLY getting to that `regPay = float(wage)*hours` line (that assigns `regPay`) when `int(hours)` is between 0 and 40. If it's >= 41, it never gets in there!

The incredibly long don't ever do this version of this code would be:

```
OVERTIMERATE = 1.5 # maybe 2?
first,last,hours,wage = line.split(',')
hours, wage = int(hours), float(wage) # Decimal is better here, but...
OTpay, regPay = 0,0 # initialize
while hours > 40:
    hours -= 1
    OTpay += wage*OVERTIMERATE
while hours > 0:
    hours -= 1
    regPay += wage
```

#### EDIT PER COMMENTS

```
reg_hours = min(int(hours), 40)
timeandhalf_hours = min(max(int(hours)-reg_hours),0),5)
doubletime_hours = max(int(hours) - (reg_hours + timeandhalf_hours), 0)

regPay = float(wage) * reg_hours
timeandhalfPay = float(wage) * 1.5 * timeandhalf_hours
doubletime_hours = float(wage) * 2 * doubletime_hours
```

Again the long form:

```
total_pay = 0
hours = int(hours)
wage = float(wage)

for i in range(1,hours+1):
    if i <= 40:
        total_pay += wage
    elif i <= 45:
        total_pay += wage * 1.5
    else:
        total_pay += wage * 2
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. But i actually have to calculate time and a half AND doubletime. So how can i change the max(hours-40) so its only between the hours 41 and 45 inclusive? Then doubletime will be anything over 45 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full version of how I'd approach the problem:

```
for line in infile: 
    first, last, hours, wage = line.split(',')
    hours, wage = int(hours), float(wage)
    if hours > 0: 
        regHours = min(hours, 40) # limit to 40
        otHours = max(hours - 40, 0)
        otHours = min(otHours, 5) # limit to 5
        dblHours = max(hours - 45, 0) # no limit
        regPay = regHours * wage
        otPay = otHours * wage * 1.5
        dblPay = dblHours * wage * 2
    else:
        regPay = 0
        otPay = 0
        dblPay = 0
    totalPay = regPay + otPay + dblPay

    print(first, last, hours, wage, totalPay)
```

And some quick results:

```
('chris', 'a', 50, 10.0, 575.0)
('chris', 'b', 41, 10.0, 415.0)
('chris', 'c', 35, 10.0, 350.0)
```